# Log 4j referencing input

Tags: java, log4j

I would like to reference input on my log 4j properties file such that when it recieves an input command externally it looks it up on a list and acts accordingly.

This is how it looks like:

```
log4j.appender.R.File=/home/oracle/conf/ATL_${log_file_name}/ATL_${log_file_name}.dlg
```

where ${log_file_name} is an integer passed on the d-switch

now the integer is referenced to the list:

1-Food

2-Fruits

3-Vegetables

such that when ${log_file_name} is 1, the command will become:

log4j.appender.R.File=/home/oracle/conf/ATL_food/ATL_food.log

how can I set this on the properties file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature for the log4j properties file.

However, you can add a file appender to the root logger programmatically, see the example below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.log4j.*;

public class LogTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String category = System.getProperty("logCategory");
        Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"); // replace with your layout
        String logFileName = "/home/oracle/conf/ATL_" + category + "/ATL_" + category + ".dlg";
        rootLogger.addAppender(new FileAppender(layout, logFileName, false));
    }
}
```

You pass a VM parameter `-DlogCategory=food` on the command line. You can do a numeric replacement yourself.